# Discrepancy between Matlab and Mathematica

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, control-systems

*What is the difference between how Matlab and Mathematica solve **State-Space** and **Transfer Function** models*?

I have a $16 \times 16$ state space system for which I am calculating transfer function. Mathematica and Matlab give me completely different answers. I can imagine truncation may lead to slightly different answers but what I get is a **huge difference**. I have checked the difference in numerical values to check the conditioning. There is no significant difference. I give the matrix as seen in Mathematica to you to check.

Please find the code attached!

```
a={{-(350103/48500), -14.9811, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {1.75898, -6.08528, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {12.4114, -32.0709, 310.284, 
0, -19.63, -102.059, -310.284, 77.9757, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {2.21387, -5.72064, 55.3468, 0, -0.454893, -21.6178, -55.3468, 
13.9089, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, -2.584, 25, 0, -1, -7.016, -25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 12.4114, -32.0709, 310.284, 
0, -19.63, -102.059, -310.284, 77.9757, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
2.21387, -5.72064, 55.3468, 0, -0.454893, -21.6178, -55.3468, 
13.9089, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -2.584, 25, 0, -1, -7.016, -25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12.4114, -32.0709, 310.284, 
0, -19.63, -102.059, -310.284, 77.9757}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2.21387, -5.72064, 55.3468, 0, -0.454893, -21.6178, -55.3468, 
13.9089}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -2.584, 25, 0, -1, -7.016, -25, 0}};

b={{116319/1940}, {10.695}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, 
{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}};

c={{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1}};

sys = StateSpaceModel[{a,b,c}]

BodePlot[sys, {2 \[Pi] 0.01, 2 \[Pi] 100}, 
ScalingFunctions -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, "Degree"}}, 
PhaseRange -> {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize ->Large]
```

Corresponding Matlab code with the same set of matrices:

```
[num,den] = ss2tf(a,b,c,[0;0;0]);

P1 = tf(num(1,:),den);
P2 = tf(num(2,:),den);
P3 = tf(num(3,:),den);

figure; bode(P1,P2,P3);
```

The transfer function that I can from Matlab and Mathematica are completely different in nature. I am pretty sure that ***according to theory Matlab gives me the right answer***. But why is Mathematica so off the mark?

Could it be any of the following?

1. Precision/truncation
2. Size of the system
3. Conditioning

Edit:
I have included the plots for both. Left is Mathematica and right is Matlab. The colors correspond to each other. Please take note of the Magnitude scale for both!
[image]

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: For reference, can you include both the *Mathematica* and MATLAB results?

Comment: @J.M. Please see the edit. I hope this was what you asked for!

Comment: I'd add that you really need to provide the *Mathematica* code, too.

Comment: @JimBaldwin ...after you define the matrices like this, the code is simply 
    sys = StateSpaceModel[{A,B,C,D}];
    BodePlot[sys,{freq_range}]

Comment: Put another way:  If you include the code, then you are much more likely to get assistance.  Some of the best advice many times comes from folks who have no idea of your subject matter but do know how to program *Mathematica*.  (I see you've added code in the comments.  But you've only given `freq_range` which is undefined.  Please include the full code in your question rather than the comments.)

Comment: @Zero, to reiterate what JimBaldwin said, please include the complete code. It is nontrivial and error-prone to be entering a system with 16 states and 3 outputs, and it is wasted time to repeat it if you have already done so.

Comment: I hope this helps...please remove the downvote if your query is solved. Or let me know what more information is to be added. thanks

Comment: @Zero Please also include the MATLAB code so that people can test that (if they happen to have MATLAB installed). At the very least, someone might be able to visually spot check some issues, if any.

Comment: Thanks.  It does help.  Note that `C` and `D` are reserved words in *Mathematica* and that the code given does not run because of that.  One should avoid variable names with uppercase letters in *Mathematica*.  After changing to `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` the code runs as advertised.

Comment: @JimBaldwin yeah i agree...i used SysA and the likes...but just for simplicity did this...i forgot about the protected symbols

Comment: If you use `Rationalize` on `a` and `b`, the results match up pretty close to Matlab.

Comment: @JimBaldwin it doesn't seem to change anything for me. I used

newa=Rationalize[a];

newb=Rationalize[b];

sys=StateSpaceModel[{newa,newb,c}];

Comment: Sorry.  My suggestion wasn't entirely complete.  Use `Rationalize` to get all numbers as rational numbers:  `a = Rationalize[a,0.0000001]` and `b = Rationalize[b]`.  (In other words, completely rationalizing `a` needs a bit more help.)

Comment: Zero, as previously mentioned, please include the corresponding MATLAB code for comparison purposes.

Comment: @SubaThomas yeah it seemed to work..but I have this warning "The highest power term *matrix* in the resolvent matrix expansion is not a zero matrix. The result may be inaccurate. Also can you explain the reasoning? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JimBaldwin yeah it worked but with the same error as in the case of Suba Thomas...can you help with the logic behind this?

Comment: @Zero, the suggestion by JimBaldwin will suffice. There was not sufficient precision which resulted in the message and incorrect result.

Comment: @Zero, I am not getting any message after doing sys = StateSpaceModel[Rationalize[{a, b, c}, 0.0000001]]

Comment: @SubaThomas Thats perfect...thanks...these things are really hard to figure out...are you a computer science guy? just curious :)

Comment: @J.M. Is there a way to send a .mat file...i can upload the matrices since I cannot find a way to copy the matrix...in my code arrive at the matrix using a lot of code with confidential information

Comment: @Zero, I meant the MATLAB code containing your matrices and the corresponding MATLAB commands that generated your plots.

Comment: @Zero, I'm more of a curious guy, all the more because I'm a developer of the control systems functions in WL.

Comment: @J.M. done...thanks

Comment: @SubaThomas Nice...I am a controls engineer working on autonomous vehicles ;)

Comment: Somebody please remove the downvotes :(

Comment: @Zero, hopefully the downvoters come back to undo their votes when they see your edits. Otherwise, there isn't much we can do.

Comment: @J.M. I don't know if you lost interest but I wanted to hear about the MATLAB result. For me, I get similar result with a difference that the dips, as seen in the answer, go way too low for me in MATLAB which disturbs the phase plot a bit. I was wondering if it was related to tolerances set up in MATLAB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using *Mathematica* 10.4.1 (Windows 7) the following code finds a pretty good match with the Matlab results.  (And I'd argue that any differences between the two are due to differences in how the precision of the input numbers are handled.)

```
a = Rationalize[a, 0.00001];
b = Rationalize[b];

sys = StateSpaceModel[{a, b, c, d}];

BodePlot[sys, {2 π 0.01, 2 π 100},
 ScalingFunctions -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, "Degree"}},
 PhaseRange -> {-π, π}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> Large,
 PlotRange -> {{Full, {0, -400}}, {Full, {-180, 180}}},
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}]
```

[image: First BodePlot]

[image: Second BodePlot]

Answer (score 2):

In M11.3 this is much much easier to solve. Simply: use instead of d Automatic:

```
a = {{-(350103/48500), -14.9811, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0}, {1.75898, -6.08528, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {12.4114, -32.0709, 310.284,
     0, -19.63, -102.059, -310.284, 77.9757, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {2.21387, -5.72064, 55.3468, 0, -0.454893, -21.6178, -55.3468,
     13.9089, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, -2.584, 25, 0, -1, -7.016, -25, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 12.4114, -32.0709, 310.284, 
    0, -19.63, -102.059, -310.284, 77.9757, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
    2.21387, -5.72064, 55.3468, 0, -0.454893, -21.6178, -55.3468, 
    13.9089, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -2.584, 25, 0, -1, -7.016, -25, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12.4114, -32.0709, 310.284, 
    0, -19.63, -102.059, -310.284, 77.9757}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    2.21387, -5.72064, 55.3468, 0, -0.454893, -21.6178, -55.3468, 
    13.9089}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -2.584, 25, 0, -1, -7.016, -25, 0}};

b = {{116319/
     1940}, {10.695}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, \
{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}};

c = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};

a = Rationalize[a, 0.00001];
b = Rationalize[b];

sys = StateSpaceModel[{a, b, c, Automatic}]
BodePlot[sys, {2 \[Pi] 0.01, 2 \[Pi] 100}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, "Degree"}}, 
 PhaseRange -> {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotRange -> {{Full, {0, -400}}, {Full, {-180, 180}}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}]
```

Both MATLAB and Mathematica 11.3 provide the very same results.[image]